# Wordpress installation error: Error establishing a database conection

Tags: php, wordpress

While trying install wordpress i recieve following error

[image]

[image]

I use wampserver i have changed wp-config.php file and now it looks like this:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');//i used 127.0.0.1 too but no matter
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

wp-db.php file:
1379 line:

```
mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
```

1409 line:

```
$this->dbh = mysqli_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

but still no result I do not know what to do can anyone help me?

Comment: The error message says that the password you provided is wrong. So change your MySQL password for root in wp-config.php.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

answer is :

define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use wordpress locally i assume. 127.0.0.1. Then you must have a local database to store wordpress's data. something like WAMP on windows or LAMP on linux. If you already have one of these then you are probably getting an error because your database is not turned on. or you have not edited the wp-config file to include the database the username and password for the database you created. beyond that wordpress does the rest of the work.

You are not very clear of what system you are using, more info would be needed to diagnose your error completely.

so what OS?
what web server are you using? (apache WAMP or LAMP?)
is your database on?
have you edited the wp-config file to include your db info?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straightforward, but could come from a number of different sources.

What that error message means is that you have your setup file misconfigured. WordPress requires a SQL database it can create tables, read, write, and otherwise modify to make and store its content. The configuration you have set in your `wp-config.php` file is wrong.

**Steps to Fix This**

1. Make sure you have an SQL database
2. Make sure you have a user in your SQL server that can access that database fully and can log in from outside sources
3. Make sure you know the host, username (for the user previously mentioned), that user's password, and the database name
4. This is where you enter these into `wp-config.php`. By default, WordPress only comes with `wp-config-example.php` so you must set this information in that file, then rename it `wp-config.php` before navigating to your setup screen.

Also Note: It's possible WordPress cannot access your database because the user you are trying to log in with does not have outside access permissions. Might be worth checking. Also, the host is not always straightforward; if you use Dreamhost or Amazon Web Services, you cannot normally specify localhost as the location of your database server, unless you specifically set your machines to be that way.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress can't...well... "establish a database connection", enable debugging in `wp-config.php`, this will show more information about the error, it could be a wrong password or server not responding...

Add this line anywhere in the file (like [**this**](http://mergely.com/uR3d7ZEu/) ).

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

If the line is already there make sure it's `true` and not `false`.